# how to align an item to the right of it's parent center? (android layouts)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, textview

i want something like this:
[image]

i palyed with android relativelayout and it's tag like : android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" , and this give me this:

[image]

i player with other tags and combine them, but no success.

so is there any way to do this?

Comment: in your 'my_text' view try using android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"

Comment: doesn't work, it goes to right of parent.

Comment: please post your code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@android:color/black" >
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:text="YOUR TEXT" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: it works perfectly, your idea for using empty linearLayout as place holder is great.

Comment: Consider using a simple View instead of a LinearLayout (if you want it to be black) or, if it is only there to serve as an anchor but will not be visible, use a Space.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
<RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <View 
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:id="@+id/dummy"
            />
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SDADASd"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/dummy"
            android:textColor="#000000"

            />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
      or go with linearlayout...
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
        <View 
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:text="YOUR TEXT" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a transparent  view in the center of your RelativeLayout and with

```
height="match_parent"
width="15dp"//(it doesn't matter much)
```

then give your layout parameter relative to this view like

```
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/yourView"
```